# Full height of Facebook app Canvas in iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having problem that I am developing a facebook app using iframe, the problem that is coming is that my full content is not being displayed . When I inspect it through firebug then I came to know that iframe is having height: 800px so I want to increase it or set height dynamically. I have tried FB.Canvas.setSize() but it didn't work so what should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the developer app on Facebook go to the app and edit settings.
In the Facebook integration section you can set "IFrame size" to auto-resize.
Then in your app, call FB.Canvas.setAutoResize after FB.init and the canvas should resize itself to fit your content automatically.

Comment: Yes you are right and I have now already fixed that, anyways thanks

Comment: Just adding that [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/) suggests using `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow` instead because `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow` is going to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

just go to your application settings
change to auto resize

and use the function FB.Canvas.setAutoResize

as this code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
 appId  : 'your APP ID Goes Here',
 status : true, // check login status
 cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
 xfbml  : true// parse XFBML
 });

 FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);

 </script>



<?php


for($i=1;$i<100;$i++)
 {

  echo "$i<br>";

  }
  ?>
```

this will make 99 lines with autoresize

Comment: You are welcome  any way we found just a bug using this function http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.caNvas.setautoresize/ you just try to put this function at the end of your page to be active